# Mac Sierra, iCloud > Notes is greyed out

Tags: macos, notes.app

I recently updated to MacOS Sierra Version 10.12.2. In the *System Preferences > Internet Accounts > iCloud > Notes*. The **Notes application is *greyed out***. It was working fine in El Capitan. Did someone face this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spent 45 minutes on the phone with Apple Support trying to fix this.  In the end they told me to try and re-install Sierra using recovery mode.  I did that, which doesn't wipe everything, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Still happens for me even with High Sierra upgrade.  Apple has told me to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

I launched reminders and clicked reminders->add account from the menu.  I logged in with the same iTunes account that is already setup in System Preferences->Internet Accounts.

Reminders and System Preferences crashed, but then I could see reminders and notes selected in System Preferences->iCloud.  I can now see notes and reminders across my Mac and iPhone.

The options in System Preferences->iCloud are still greyed out.

Comment: I do however keep losing reminders as a checked option in iCloud.  At times I can re-add it but now it's unchecked along with notes and I can't seem to get it back by deleting the iCloud account and re-adding.